# Codename One: update plugin error in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, plugins, codenameone, updates

When I try to update the Codename One plugin in NetBeans (8.0.2), I get this error message:
"Unable to connect to the CodenameOnePlugin Update Center because of Received fatal alert: handshake_failure". The URL used is https://www.codenameone.com/files/netbeans/updates.xml.
Is there a solution for this?

It was mentioned before in a NetBeans 11.1 issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2916.

My current plugin version is 6.0 (last check 2019/11/11), is this the latest one?

Comment: Which JVM is running netbeans in your machine? Not the one running within Netbeans but the one defined to run netbeans itself in your configuration. Make sure it's a recent update of JDK 8

Comment: Thank you. Updating to the latest JDK 8 update solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem in nb 8.2 Java version: 1.8.0_192 Please help me